# Storing fragments to deal with screen rotation changes

Tags: android, fragment, screen-rotation

I have an application that is composed of one activity and 3 fragments. The activity creates a menu with buttons that create the appropriate fragments. My code works perfectly without screen rotations, but it breaks when I rotate the screen.

My first attempt did not include a `setRetainInstance(true)` call when creating the fragments. The issue that I found with that is that after replacing fragments twice (one fragment remains on the back stack), if I rotate the screen, I get a null pointer exception in the fragment that is not currently displayed. **Edit: Just a note, the null pointer exception is in the `setOnItemClickListener` call shown below.  `lv` is declared in the `onCreateView()` method.**

My second attempt, I included a `setRetainInstance(true)` call when creating the fragments.  This solved the first issue. However, one of my fragments is a `ListFragment`, and when I rotate the screen, the `OnItemClickListener` does not seem to be set anymore. Here is my code for setting the listener:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
        gameslist, R.layout.list_object,
        new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_LOCATION, TAG_CREATED },
        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.location, R.id.created_date });
setListAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // ...
        }
});
```

Any ideas or solutions to this problem? Is my understanding of how to design with fragments just completely off?

Thanks for any help!

edit: also, just for my understanding, where in the code are the fragments being recreated?  They are not in the `oncreate()` function of my activity.  Thanks!

Figured it out! I was calling the AsyncTask in the onCreate() function, which was being called when the screen was rotated.  However, I was declaring lv in the onCreateView() function, which would not be called until the view is created.  Nullpointerexception!

Comment: do you have onCreate(...) and onResume() and onCreateView(...) implemented in your fragment?  Which one of the three is that adapter code in?

Comment: I have onCreate and onCreateView implemented.  The adapter code is in an AsyncTask called by onCreate. Thanks.

Comment: one last thing-- the adapter code is in the OnPostExecute method, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have onCreate(...) and onResume() and onCreateView(...) implemented in your fragment?

Which one of the three is that adapter code in?